# Paperclip: proper file name is not validate while saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, extension-methods

I am using rails 3.1.
I am trying to upload .docx file without proper file name (it contains only extension 'docx'), while saving it should validate like "file name is invalid".

In model,

```
validates_attachment_presence :document
validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 5.megabytes, :message => "should be    less than 5Mb"
validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ['application/txt', 'text/plain', 
'application/pdf', 'application/msword',
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
'application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
'application/rtf', 'application/x-rtf', 'text/rtf', 'text/richtext', 'application/doc', 'application/x-soffice', 'application/octet-stream']
```

Paperclip gem which i am using,

```
paperclip (3.0.4, 2.8.0, 2.4.5)
```

Eg : I am trying to upload ' .docx' file.

Please suggest how to avoid saving these kind of files.

Comment: Are you making any validations on the model?
Can you give an example of a filename you are trying to upload?

Comment: I have edited my question as per to your question.